# Construct an array with ES6-style imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to convert some Node javascript code to typescript, which means converting `require()`s to `import`s.

Here is the original javascript:

```js
const stuff = [
    require("./elsewhere/part1"),
    require("./elsewhere/part2"),
    // ...
];
```

Node-style `require()`s return an object, but ES6-style `import`s don't:

```js
import part1 from "./elsewhere/part1"
// ...

const stuff = [ part1, /* ... */];
```

What can I do to retain the clean look of the original javascript in typescript?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only option would be to use dynamic imports instead, since they return a Promise, but it has the drawback of making everything asynchronous, even if it isn't:

```
const stuff = await Promise.all([
    import("./elsewhere/part1"),
    import("./elsewhere/part2"),
    // ...
]);
```

I'd prefer your original version of static imports.

Comment: Well that sucks... I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has better ideas.